# MacBook Air Battery is not charging, no light, still be able to power up, battery condition is normal

Tags: battery, magsafe

I experienced this behavior two days ago (My MacBook Air is late 2011 version (4.2):

- I can still power up my Mac, with or without MacSafe charger connected
- Battery is not charging
- There is no light.
- I tried to reset SMC but it does not help
- Battery condition is normal
- I tried with few different MagSafe charger but still can't charge my MacBook Air

What is the problem and what should I do?

Here is the result of System Information:

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
  Serial Number:    xxxxxxxxxx
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 406
  Hardware Revision:    000a
  Cell Revision:    162
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   4743
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   5788
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  269
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    0
  Voltage (mV): 8032

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    10
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  Current Power Source: Yes
  DarkWakeBackgroundTasks:  1
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  1
  Battery Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    2
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  DarkWakeBackgroundTasks:  0
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  Reduce Brightness:    Yes
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  1

Hardware Configuration:

  UPS Installed:    No

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x0000
  Revision: 0x0000
  Family:   0x0000
  Serial Number:    0x00000000
  Charging: No
```

Comment: did you inspect the magsafe female plug (on your computer), clean it with alcohol.

Comment: Yep I already did that.

Comment: Did you check the fuse box for the power outlet ?

Comment: SMC reset can be tricky on MBA, redo it following this procedure http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

Comment: Yes I even used 3 different MagSafe charger, including 1 from Thunderbolt Display. No help

Comment: After resetting SMC and fire up my Mac, battery is not detected. I need to restart one more time. Is this the behavior?

Comment: In rare occasions battery do die to early! (there is a small circuit on the battery responsible for the power management.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MacBook Air sometimes doesn't charge when the charger is plugged in](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55255/my-macbook-air-sometimes-doesnt-charge-when-the-charger-is-plugged-in)

Comment: @hippietrail No it's not.

Comment: Have you tried using different plugs in your house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not normal obviously but this could be a sign that something is wrong with the hardware.

The best advice is to go to an Apple store or an Apple Authorized Service Provider and let them look at it.

The issue could be your battery, it could be the MagSafe board or it could be the logic board.

I wish I could help you more but without seeing the unit with my own eyes and taking it apart I can't say for certain what it is. I doubt it is software and therefore encourage you to [reach out and find someone who is certified to open Macs](https://locate.apple.com/country).

Comment: @Buscar웃 I think it is in this case more important what the questioner thinks of my answer rather than your thoughts on the matter. Saying it is hardware rather than software isn't entirely vague but I can't test his hardware now can I? It has to be done by someone else and so I gave him the tools to find someone who can. Also, at least I gave an answer rather than just a comment. My answer is based off of experience and the info provided in OP and comments.

Comment: It is not more important what the OP thinks about your answer. This is a public place not a personal conversation. In addition your answer would be viewed by others seeking similar help. I explained why the negative vote, while I did not had to do that and could have staid anonymous. So take my feed back as is -well meant.

Comment: This is largely caused by hardware issues and I think this answer is accurate for the OP considering he doesn’t know what to do in this situation (in worst case, assuming software’s fault). Better take the machine for the certified Apple Genius to check and avoid needless tinkering.

Comment: So I took my MacAir to Apple Genius Bar. Turn out there was a problem with MagSafe board. They replaced it for me and everything is working fine now. Thank @Buscar웃 ...

Comment: and @AndrewU. (since SE only allow 1 tag per comment)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no light.

- Change your charger.
- Clean your charger and laptop connectors.
- Go to Apple Genius Bar.

---

If there is a light.

- Go to the Apple in the upper left corner and select **About This Mac**, then click on **More Info** (and then **System Report** if you are running 10.7 Lion, 10.8 Mountain Lion or 10.9 Mavericks), then select **Power** from the left hand column of the **System Profiler**. Then check **Battery Information** from the top of the page. This could be useful.
- Check your charger for the power parameters (Watts), it could be too low for your needs.
- Check your battery health and and the current charge by installing [coconutBattery app](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/).
- Try to reset your SMC.

  > Try pressing the left side keyboard 'Shift-control-option and power
  >   buttons at the same time and then releasing them. This resets the SMC
  >   and sometimes it solve the battery not charging issue on Macs.
- > It’s important to keep track of your power consumption on a Macbook
  >   Air or Pro, since that will determine how long you can use the thing
  >   before you have to plug it in again. Mavericks makes it easy to see
  >   the top app or two that uses the most energy on your Mac with a quick
  >   Option-Click on the battery menubar icon, letting you know which apps
  >   are consuming the most energy.

Answer (score 1):

Warm up your MagSafe Charger square.

Comment: What does this mean ?

Comment: @JashJacob: It means the same as [Rose's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/165085/11513).

Answer (score 1):

its cold!

sit on it for a while ( the big square part)
and it'll be good as new!

don't waste your time going to apple :p

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting the free app [CoconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/). It will run diagnostics on your battery and tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with your MacBook A1278 A1286 MagSafe DC-In Power.