# MacBook Pro Retina 15'' Late 2013 Stoppped Charging

Tags: charging, magsafe, logicboard

Related questions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131958/macbook-air-battery-is-not-charging-no-light-still-be-able-to-power-up-batter) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170601/battery-is-not-charging-despite-smc-reset).

Hi everyone. This is what happened to me:

I was giving a class, in a 200 people auditorium, and there were lots of power extensions and cables for everyone to connect their laptops while the class. I was running out of battery (about 20%) so I decided to plug my MBP to one of those connectors. I didn't notice if it started charging or not, I just trusted it would. Then after 20 min aprox, we had an hour off the auditorium, and when we got back, I connected the machine again, but this time I noticed the light in the charger didn't work. I thought it was an issue with the power, I changed the place but the MBP was not receiving any power.

I asked to my students for a different charger (thinking it was a charger issue) but trying 2 different ones, still light didn't turned on, so I thought it was an internal hardware issue. (at this point the MBP was still on, with 5% battery or so).

After class, I took the MBP to an official Apple Service center, they told me it was the "Magsafe" (like an internal little board that allows power from charger to battery?) and the charger, both of them seemed to be damaged. Most likely an overpower incident. I understood since it made sense.

Now issue is they asked warranty Magsafe piece, the installed it but machine still not turning on. THey say at Apple Service retailer that could be Logic Board, but does that even make sense? Could a MBP still be on and working if logic board is damaged? I mean, the machine never got turned off, it was alive until battery drained out...

Now we are waiting another freaking 4-5 days to get the logic board. I'm getting crazy since that machine is my main work tool. What do you guys think it could be?

## EDIT

Now, I get that this specific model's parts are all welded, so, a new logic board would mean what other new pieces? I'm worried about the data in my hard drive.

Comment: I'm not going to offer an opinion as to what the issue is since you've already taken it to Apple however I will say that if you've been maintaining proper backups along the way, as one is supposed to, you should not have to worry about any data loss other than what's been created since your last backup.  If you haven't been backing it up then it will be a hard lesson learned if the data is missing.

Comment: @user3439894 fortunately I have most of my info in cloud services. The last few commits in some software projects I didn't push are the ones I'm worried about. Thanks for your opinion though

Comment: "It could need a new logic board" seems to be Apple's mantra these days. A few years back I repaired a couple of G4 portables for a friend, a Ti PowerBook with no display and the other, a white iBook which wouldn't power on. He'd taken both to an Apple store and both came back with quotes for new logic boards. The TiBook actually had a failed display cable (VGA output worked fine, not tested by Apple) - a replacement display and casing sorted that and the iBook needed the power socket resoldering. Both were fixed for £100 worth of parts so don't always take Apple's word as gospel...

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly, Assuming the power supply is functioning properly then there are only 2 printed circuit boards in play in the Late 2013 MacBook Pro Retina 15" in this scenario, the MagSafe PCB and the Main PCB (or logic board).  So if the MagSafe PCB tests out okay then, again assuming the power supply is functioning properly, the only component left in this scenario is the Main Logic Board.  There are not a lot of separate parts in these newer Mac notebooks. :)  That said, I agree to not blindly trust what any tech says without a second look by someone else who's qualified.

Comment: If you've tried other power adapters with the same result then it's definitely looking like it's an issue with the MacBook. If it was my machine I'd disconnect the battery, possibly overnight, and let the SMC completely clear its settings. The recommended procedure doesn't always completely reset the SMC, disconnecting the battery can give it a "deeper" reset (my SD card reader occasionally disappears, SMC reset doesn't restore it but disconnecting the battery for a while does the trick). It may not help but it won't cost you anything to find out if you follow one of the many guides available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everyone thanks a lot for your answers and comments, it turned out magsafe, logic board and charger, all three needed to be replaced. Seems that logic board is not mandatory for the Mbp to be on.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the logic board needs to be replaced.

I would try resetting your SMC (manages the power in the laptop):

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.
3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
   Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

For the full Apple KB Article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: thedanielmatt, unmultimedio stated he already took it to an official Apple Service center and reseting the SMC is standard operation procedure for Apple certified technicians to preform, especially in cases such as this.  So while your advice certainly is good and should be followed nonetheless I'd be surprised if that wasn't already done by the tech, especially in light of saying the logic board needs to be replaced.

Comment: I had considered it may have already been performed, but if it was a 3rd party AASP (or even a Genius Bar), they may not have done it.  Figured I'd throw it out there just in case.

Comment: Which is why I said "..So while your advice certainly is good and should be followed..." :)